# Подскажите что не правильно моей архитектуре классов?

Tags: c#, ооп

Подскажите что не правильно моей архитектуре классов, препод говорит что не правильная архитектура классов, чего не правильного-то ?)[image: <code>введите сюда описание изображения</code>]`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication97
{
    abstract class Securities
    {
        string fullName;
        string shortName;
        string issuerName;
        DateTime dateOfEmission;
        double volume;

        public Securities()
        {

        }

        public Securities(string f, string sh, string iss, DateTime de, double v)
        {
            FullName = f;
            ShortName = sh;
            IssuerName = iss;
            DateOfEmission = de;
            Volume = v;
        }


        protected string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return fullName;
            }

            set
            {
                fullName = value;
            }
        }

        protected string ShortName
        {
            get
            {
                return shortName;
            }

            set
            {
                shortName = value;
            }
        }

        protected string IssuerName
        {
            get
            {
                return issuerName;
            }

            set
            {
                issuerName = value;
            }
        }

        protected DateTime DateOfEmission
        {
            get
            {
                return dateOfEmission;
            }

            set
            {
                dateOfEmission = value;
            }
        }

        protected double Volume
        {
            get
            {
                return volume;
            }

            set
            {
                volume = value;
            }
        }

        public abstract void ChangeCurrentPrice(double cp);
        public abstract string ToStringFields();

    }

    class Share : Securities
    {
        string typeShare;
        double currentPrice;
        double balanceOfCost;
        double lotSize;

        public Share(string f, string sh, string iss, DateTime de, double v, string tysh, double cp, double bc, double ls) : base(f, sh, iss, de, v)
        {
            TypeShare = tysh;
            CurrentPrice = cp;
            BalanceOfCost = bc;
            LotSize = ls;
        }

        public Share()
        {
        }


        public string TypeShare
        {
            get
            {
                return typeShare;
            }

            set
            {
                typeShare = value;
            }
        }

        public double CurrentPrice
        {
            get
            {
                return currentPrice;
            }

            set
            {
                currentPrice = value;
            }
        }

        public double BalanceOfCost
        {
            get
            {
                return balanceOfCost;
            }

            set
            {
                balanceOfCost = value;
            }
        }

        public double LotSize
        {
            get
            {
                return lotSize;
            }

            set
            {
                lotSize = value;
            }
        }

        public override void ChangeCurrentPrice(double cp)
        {
            currentPrice = cp;
        }

        public override string ToStringFields()
        {
            return FullName + "\n" + ShortName + "\n" + IssuerName + "\n" + DateOfEmission + "\n" + Volume + "\n" +
            TypeShare + "\n" + CurrentPrice + "\n" + BalanceOfCost + "\n" + LotSize + "\n-----------------------------";
        }

        public double CalcAmountOfDevidends(bool t)
        {

            if (typeShare == "Обычная")
            {
                return balanceOfCost * 0.05;
            }
            else
            {
                if (t)
                {
                    return balanceOfCost * 0.05;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class Bond : Securities
    {
        string typeBond;
        double ratedCost;
        double currentPrice;
        DateTime datePerformance;
        double percentCoupon;

        public Bond(string f, string sh, string iss, DateTime de, double v, string tyB, double rC, double cp, DateTime dP, double pc) : base(f, sh, iss, de, v)
        {
            TypeBond = tyB;
            RatedCost = rC;
            CurrentPrice = cp;
            DatePerformance = dP;
            PercentCoupon = pc;
        }

        public Bond()
        {

        }

        public string TypeBond
        {
            get
            {
                return typeBond;
            }

            set
            {
                typeBond = value;
            }
        }

        public double RatedCost
        {
            get
            {
                return ratedCost;
            }

            set
            {
                ratedCost = value;
            }
        }

        public double CurrentPrice
        {
            get
            {
                return currentPrice;
            }

            set
            {
                currentPrice = value;
            }
        }

        public DateTime DatePerformance
        {
            get
            {
                return datePerformance;
            }

            set
            {
                datePerformance = value;
            }
        }

        public double PercentCoupon
        {
            get
            {
                return percentCoupon;
            }

            set
            {
                percentCoupon = value;
            }
        }

        public override void ChangeCurrentPrice(double cp)
        {
            CurrentPrice = cp;
        }

        public override string ToStringFields()
        {
            return FullName + "\n" + ShortName + "\n" + IssuerName + "\n" + DatePerformance + "\n" + Volume + "\n" +
            TypeBond + "\n" + RatedCost + "\n" + CurrentPrice + "\n" + DatePerformance + "\n" + PercentCoupon + "\n-----------------------------";
        }

        public double CalcSumCoupon()
        {
            if (TypeBond == "Купон")
            {
                05.06.16
            return PercentCoupon * RatedCost;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }


    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Securities> list = new List<Securities>();

            list.Add(new Bond("ПУБЛИЧНОЕ АКЦИОНЕРНОЕ ОБЩЕСТВО «ГОРНО - МЕТАЛЛУРГИЧЕСКАЯ КОМПАНИЯ» «НОРИЛЬСКИЙ НИКЕЛЬ»",
            "ПАО ГОРНО - МЕТАЛЛУРГИЧЕСКАЯ КОМПАНИЯ НОРИЛЬСКИЙ НИКЕЛЬ",
            "ОАО «Российское акционерное общество «Норильский никель», ОАО «РАО «Норильский никель»",
            new DateTime(2016, 10, 1), 3500, "Дисконтная", 150, 45, new DateTime(2016, 11, 1), 0.15));

            list.Add(new Share("Ростелеком(ПАО) АО", "Ростел-AO", "RTKM", new DateTime(2013, 5, 6), 6000, "Обычная", 47,
            45, 48));

            list.Add(new Share("акц.пр. ОАО АК Транснефть", "Транснф АП", "TRNFP", new DateTime(2013, 5, 6), 6500, "Привилегированная", 45, 36, 46));
            list.Add(new Bond("АКЦИОНЕРНОЕ ОБЩЕСТВО «АЛЬФА-БАНК»", "АО «АЛЬФА-БАНК»", "Альфа-Банк",
            new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), 5000, "Купонная", 200, 15, new DateTime(2015, 2, 1), 0.11));

            list.Insert(0,
            new Bond("Публичное акционерное общество «Сбербанк России»", "АО «АЛЬФА-БАНК»", "ПАО Сбербанк",
            new DateTime(2014, 1, 1), 4000, "Купонная", 400, 25, new DateTime(2014, 3, 1), 0.08)); //доб.в начало списка 

            list.RemoveAt(1); //удаление из списка 2 элемента 
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (new Random().Next() % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        if (typeof(Bond) == list[i].GetType())
                        {
                            list[i].ChangeCurrentPrice(((Bond)(list[i])).CurrentPrice + new Random().NextDouble());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            list[i].ChangeCurrentPrice(((Share)(list[i])).CurrentPrice + new Random().NextDouble());
                        }
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(1000, 10000));
                foreach (var sec in list)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sec.ToStringFields());
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что именно не устраивает преподавателя, уточнять всё таки лучше у него. В классах вот так сразу ничего криминального не видно.

Comment: Не вижу ничего криминального в архитектуре, только пару недочетов в типах и использование возможностей языка. Что не устраивает преподавателя, надо уточнять у него самого.

Comment: Не проставлены явно модификаторы доступа, ошибки в коде, неоднородные отступы, невнятный неймспейс, не использование возможностей языка. Докопаться можно до чего угодно. Без комментария препода Вам тут не помогут.

Answer (score 5):

У Вас все проперти в базовам класе protected, это не позволит обратится к ним снаружи. Либо придется в каждом классе писать геторы/сеторы на каждое проперти (что не совсем логично), либо переписать проперти как то так:

```
public string FullName
{
    get { return fullName; }
    protected set{ fullName = value; } //так сетер будет протектнутым
}
```

В справочной информации к Вашей контрольной скорей всего на это намекается.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема не столько в иерархии классов, в ней как раз все нормально, а в архитектуре, читай коде, самих классов.

1. Насколько я понимаю, ценные бумаги не могут менять свой тип, название, эмитента, и дату эмиссии, следовательно эти параметры должны задаваться в конструкторе и иметь свойства только для чтения, без `set` либо с `private set`. Конструктор без параметров в вашем случае неприменим с точки зрения логики, т.к. ценная бумага в принципе не может быть без, перечисленного выше, набора неизменяемых свойств. Соответственно нужно определить конструкторы с соответствующим набором параметров.
2. Для вывода в виде строки не нужно создавать отдельный метод, достаточно переопределить стандартный метод `ToString` унаследованный от `Object`, т.к. он ни чего полезного все равно в базовом варианте не делает. Хотя это уже на любителя и по условиям конкретной задачи, для учебного задания такой вариант более чем пригоден.
3. Текущая цена есть у всех ценных бумаг из вашего задания, поэтому это поле и  метод для него можно вынести в базовый класс, несмотря на то, что это явно не написано. Для того он и базовый, чтобы вмещать в себя общие элементы.
4. Тип ценной бумаги, как и вид, лучше сделать перечислением, а не строкой, т.к. видов и типов ограниченное количество, а строки требуют дополнительной проверки на корректность при присваивании, с перечислениями это немного проще, да и в коде смотрится лучше.
5. Для всех полей указать уровень доступа `private` и снабдить свойствами с геттерами и сеттерами с необходимыми уровнями доступа.

Про ошибку с `protected` свойствами вам уже написали. Вообще все что я написал вам должны были объяснять на лекциях.